# Sort matrix (or data.frame) on amount of unique values per column

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, matrix

How to `reorder` columns of a `data.frame` on the total amount of unique values per column? As an example:

```
var1 var2 var3
  1    1   1
  0    2   2
  1    3   3
  0    4   1
  1    5   2
```

Is there a way to reorder this like `var2, var3, var1` automatically (because the length of unique values are 5, 3, and 2 respectively, or the opposite, 2 3 5)?

In this case it is not that difficult to get what we want, but in my case I've many columns. Is there a way to do this type of sorting automatically?

Also, I'd prefer to have a solution that works on `matrix` (in addition to `data.frame`), independent of whether there are column names or not.

Comment: Are you asking about *reordering* columns or *sorting* them?

Comment: Reordening columns, I'll update.

Comment: Dualinity, I've edited the post to clarify somethings.

Comment: Thank you, you made it into a more general, appropriate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df[names(sort(sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x))), decreasing = TRUE))]

#   var2 var3 var1
# 1    1    1    1
# 2    2    2    0
# 3    3    3    1
# 4    4    1    0
# 5    5    2    1
```

If your input is a `matrix`, then:

```
m[, names(sort(apply(m, 2, function(x) 
       length(unique(x))), decreasing = TRUE))]
```

should work.

```
#      var2 var3 var1
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    2    2    0
# [3,]    3    3    1
# [4,]    4    1    0
# [5,]    5    2    1
```

**Edit:** your example in the post seems to have column names, but this one you gave in your comments doesn't. Please make sure to produce the example correctly.

```
X <- cbind(1, rnorm(10), 1:10)
```

Since you can't expect column names, you'll have to return indices. Try this (it'll work if you've column names or not, of course):

```
m[, sort(apply(X, 2, function(x) 
         length(unique(x))), decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)$ix]
```

Comment: +1 Argh, beat you by 16 seconds, but not with the good answer !

Comment: I get an empty matrix back

Comment: Does your matrix have `column names`?

Comment: `X <- cbind(1, rnorm(10), 1:10)`

Comment: Yea, my bad. I only added the names in order to be able to explain things more easily, but I guess it changes the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using `order`,

```
dat[,order(apply(dat,2,function(x) length(unique(x))),decreasing = TRUE)]
  var2 var3 var1
1    1    1    1
2    2    2    0
3    3    3    1
4    4    1    0
5    5    2    1
```

Now if we put remove colnames, we stille get the good result but with a warning

```
 colnames(dat) <- NULL
 dat[,order(apply(dat,2,function(x) length(unique(x))),decreasing = TRUE)]
  NA NA NA
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  0
3  3  3  1
4  4  1  0
5  5  2  1
```

**EDIT** test performance:

I test on a matrix with 1000 columns. the 2 solutions times are comparable, with a slight gain for `order`.

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(100*1000),ncol=1000,nrow=100)
Arun <- function() X[, sort(apply(X, 2, function(x) 
  length(unique(x))), decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)$ix]

AgStudy <- function()  X[,order(apply(X,2,function(x) length(unique(x))),decreasing = TRUE)]

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(Arun(),AgStudy())

Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
1 AgStudy() 28.04634 32.37105 34.73820 36.49930 129.6048
2    Arun() 31.15476 32.97180 36.24027 37.91584 132.3871
```